# How to Passing Uiimage from one view controller to Other view controller when using popvivew controller used?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, crop, popviewcontroller

I Have Two View controllers.

1. First UIViewController contain one UIImage, when I click "crop" button, go to second view controller I pass the image by push view controller, here I'am cropping my UIImage.
2. In second UIViewController after cropping my image, clicking "done" button, I need to pass the cropped image to first view.

Problem is when I use pop-view controller, image is not passing.

Comment: How you are passing image when pop?

Comment: Could you provide some code on how you are trying to pass the image object?

Comment: In first View -(void)btn_Press
{
    croppedViewcontroller* myCropImg = [[croppedViewcontrolleralloc]initWithNibName:@"croppedViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    
    [myCropImg setScrollView:self.img.image];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myCropImg animated:YES];
} /////here i'm doing cropping.   targetview.imageview.image = self.image;
   
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: may I know?where is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. First view controller should have a property

```
@property (assign)UIImage *croppedImage;
```

Second view controller should have

```
@property (assign)FirstViewController *first;
```

Before popping set

```
first.croppedImage = self.image;
```

Comment: How you are popping? Do that when done button pressed itself it will work

Comment: yes.i had created the object,set the property and synthesize that,and i passing the image.

Comment: If you are looking for singleton class look into the link.[Singleton class](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

1)Make a UIIMAGE *variable in first view controllers header.

2)set the uiimage variable from second view controller before popping.

3)POP the second view controller.

If this is not working make a singleton class consisting of uiimage variable