# How to Passing Uiimage from one view controller to Other view controller when using push view controller used?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I Have three View controllers.

**First UIViewController contain one `UIImage`, when I click "crop" button, go to second view controller I pass the image by push view controller, here I'am cropping my `UIImage`.
In second `UIViewController` which is inherited from image editor Viewcontroller after cropping my image, clicking "done" button.**

I need to pass the cropped image to another view controller where i am having share button to share the post.

Problem is when I am puishing the editted image to another view controller in which share button is present,image is not passing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640456/how-to-passing-uiimage-from-one-view-controller-to-other-view-controller-when-us and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353248/passing-a-uiimage-from-one-view-controller-to-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: how are you passing image to another view controller

Comment: by using initwith image method i am passing the image from one view controller to another and also i am passing the editted image as imageview.image = v2.image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delegation**

You implement the protocol on your `View Controller`

In `Controller.h`:

```
@class Controller;

@protocol ControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)sendFrom:(Controller *)controller
                   image:(UIImage *)image;

@end

@interface Controller : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSObject <ControllerDelegate> * delegate;

@end
```

In `Controller.m` when you want send the image:

```
[self.delegate sendFrom:self
         image: self.image];
```

After on your `Detail View Controller`, don't forget to assign it as delegate of the `Controller`. And to implement the `ControllerDelegate` protocol. To do that:

In your `DetailController.h` implement the protocol. You can do that on your .m as well.

```
#import "Controller.h"

@interface DetailController : UIViewController <ControllerDelegate>
```

You keep a reference of the `Controller` in The `Detail Controller`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *controller;
```

And assign its `delegate` in the `viewDidLoad` of the `Detail Controller`. For example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated{

      [super viewDidLoad:animated];

      self.controller.delegate = self;
   }
```

Don't forget to implement the `protocol method` in your Detail View. Here you receive the image you passed from Controller and you save it in your `Detail Controller` `UIImage` property:

```
- (void)sendFrom:(Controller *)controller
                       image:(UIImage *)image{

   self.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the image in the Detail Controller before you make the push?

```
DetailController *detailVC=[[DetailController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"DetailController"
                          bundle:nil];

detailVC.image = self.image;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: but the same code i have tried it is not displaying the editted image in the share view controller i.e, in third view controller

Comment: Try to pass the info as well with Delegaton, Notifications or Key Value Coding

Comment: one more thing that i like to say is the second view controller i am doing deep copy of image as an edited image so can u please go through the code

Comment: - (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self){
        originalImage = [image deepCopy];
        
        NSLog(@"original image is %@",originalImage);
        
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: the above original image is having the edited image and i need to send it to share view controller after clicking on share button i should share the image

Comment: for displaying the image in another view controller i am using this below code  [_pickedImageView setImage:_clView.originalImage];

Answer (score 0):

You can implement storyboard segue to your detail controller and use following sample code.

```
- (void)cropButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        DetailController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        [detailVC setImage:self.image];
    }
}
```